# WPF Application With Multiple Child Views - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My problem is quite simple, I want to have a MainView which in turn will have multiple Views which are dynamic and intractable, like in the diagram below:

[image]

But to do this you need multiple ViewModels, and I do not know how to organise them.

My original Idea is to have a `MainViewModel`, within which I will create properties that will return all my `ChildViewModels` as shown below, but It seems unprofessional to me and a bad practice.

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private EditPropertiesViewModel _editPropertiesViewModel;
    public EditPropertiesViewModel EditPropertiesViewModel
    {
        get { return _editPropertiesViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _editPropertiesViewModel = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }


    private UsersDetailsViewModel _usersDetailsViewModel;
    public UsersDetailsViewModel UsersDetailViewModel
    {
        get { return _usersDetailsViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _usersDetailsViewModel = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    //etc. etc..
}
```

Then from My `MainView`, I would set the Datacontext to the `MainViewModel`
Please help me I have no idea what to do, I am totally paused right now.

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "add multiple views using UserControls to my MainWindow". Are those views dynamic (i.e. you show one view or another, based on some criteria) or do you simply have multiple (static) child views?

Comment: Okay, I am going to edit my Question now, guess it was not clear

Comment: the image is prism, but I want to achieve it without prism

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to achieve this without PRISM you can make use of **ContentControl**. For every region you create ContentControl and for every ContentControl you create its ViewModel property. Then you manipulate selected ViewModel associated with ContentControl and ContentControl adjusts view based on type of ViewModel assigned. For clarification take a look 
**XAML:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SubArticleViewModel}">
        <view:SubArticleView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ArticleViewModel}"/>
```

**C#**

```
class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

class MainViewModel 
{
    public BaseViewModel ArticleViewModel { get; set; }
}

class SubArticleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

}
```

Whenever you assign

```
ArticleViewModel = new SubArticleViewModel();
```

DataTemplate defined as resource will be placed as Content of Control. 
Above way out creates a lots of work and is more vulnerable for omission. PRISM would be a better choice anyway.

Comment: I sure know prism would be better, but it does not feel okay, going to prism when I do not know how to implement it simply,  the way It should be is my first knowing how to do it the difficult way and then discovering prism

Comment: Then take advantage of above solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create AppViewModel class with **static** ctor like this:

   ```
   class AppViewModel : BaseViewModel 
   {
       static AppViewModel() 
       {
           _AppModel = new AppViewModel();
       }

       private static AppViewModel _AppModel;

       public static AppViewModel Current 
       {
           get { return _AppModel;  }
       }

       private AppViewModel()
       {
           //Initialize view models here
           MainPageModel = new MainPageViewModel();
       }

       //VIEW MODELS

       public MainPageViewModel MainPageModel { get; private set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create BaseViewModel class. All of your VM's should be inherited from it:

   ```
   class BaseViewModel //implement INotifyPropertyChanged if needed
   {
       public AppViewModel AppModel 
       {
           get { return AppViewModel.Current; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. So now you can create UserControl called "MainView":

   ```
   public partial class MainView : UserControl
   {
       public MainView()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           //Prevent view updating in Designer
           if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
           {
               return;
           }

           var mainVM = AppViewModel.Current.MainPageModel;
           DataContext = mainVM;
       }
   }
   ```
4. In the MainWindow.xaml:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="MVVM_Test.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MVVM_Test.Views"
           Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
       <views:MainView />
   </Window>
   ```